# SQLite3 DB File On Server - How Can I Use in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, database

I would like for my iPhone application to interact with a sqlite3 database file that is hosted on my server. How can I achieve this with Objective-C?

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTTP front end for you SQLITE database. That way, you can write a server side application to access your SQLITE database in any language you want:

1. ASP.NET
2. PHP
3. Java (Servlets/JSP or {insert your favorite WEB JAVA framework here})

And you can access and/or modify your SQLITE database data within your iPhone (or Mac OS) application by issuing HTTP commands with NSString's `stringWithContentsOfUrl` or any other suitable class for this purpose.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does that suggest that I could use ASIHTTPRequest for the HTTP front end and send PHP requests that way?

Comment: Yes. Although you can also use NSString (sync and simpler in my opinions, os NSUrlConnection). But you can also use ASIHTTPRequest...